# What is DW_AT code 0x05? Not found in DWARF standard

Tags: dwarf

I've code across an elf file with dwarf information produced by a tricore-gcc compiler from HighTec. It contains dwarf attribute encoding 0x05 which isn't mentioned in the standard version 4 which reads

DW_AT_sibling 0x01 reference
DW_AT_location 0x02 exprloc, loclistptr
DW_AT_name 0x03 string
DW_AT_ordering 0x09 constant

and in the standard version 5 it's "reserved". Didn't find it in any older standard either.

Anyone knows what coe 0x05 is?

Answer (score 0):

It was part of DWARF1, see [dwarf.h](https://sourceforge.net/p/libdwarf/code/ci/238b7ed01cb9a3754c36a4dbc1d8a24044ffa3dc/tree/libdwarf/dwarf.h#l259) of libdwarf:

```
#define DW_AT_sibling                           0x01
#define DW_AT_location                          0x02
#define DW_AT_name                              0x03
/* reserved DWARF1                              0x04, DWARF1 only */
/* AT_fund_type                                 0x05, DWARF1 only */
/* AT_mod_fund_type                             0x06, DWARF1 only */
/* AT_user_def_type                             0x07, DWARF1 only */
/* AT_mod_u_d_type                              0x08, DWARF1 only */
#define DW_AT_ordering                          0x09
#define DW_AT_subscr_data                       0x0a
```

And according to [DWARF 1.1](http://www.dwarfstd.org/doc/dwarf_1_1_0.pdf), `AT_fund_type` means **Fundamental Types**:

> A fundamental type is a data type that is not defined in terms of
>   other data types. Each programming language has a set of fundamental
>   types that are considered to be built into that language.